# PRQA frame configuration not showing in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have installed Jenkins 2.111 version and I installed the PRQA plugin.Then i tried to configure PRQA. In that only QA verify configuration is showing,PRQA framework configuration is not showing.

Please help me,i have to install which version of PRQA plugin and Jenkins. Thank  you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

PRQA is only running on an old version of Jenkins. jenkins-2.107.2.
In latest version of Jenkins, the devil-Jenkins will appear when you change settings.
In some browsers, the output is really nice.